# changing settings of django package installed through pip

Tags: django, django-templates, pip, django-taggit

I'm having trouble finding out how to change the settings in the `django-taggit-templatetags` package without actually going in and modifying the source code. I followed the README instructions here: https://github.com/feuervogel/django-taggit-templatetags

I basically did a pip install into my virtualenv, so the package is saved under `venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages`.

I wanted to change the <s>default</s> weight settings for the tagcloud's tags. The instructions say:

> There are a few settings to be set:
>
> TAGGIT_TAGCLOUD_MIN (default: 1.0) This specifies the minimum of the
>   weight attribute of a tagcloud's tags.
>
> TAGGIT_TAGCLOUD_MAX (default: 6.0) This specifies the maximum of the
>   weight attribute of a tagcloud's tags.
>
> If you want to use the weight as font-sizes, just do as follows:
>
> `<font size={{tag.weight|floatformat:0}}>{{tag}}</font>`
>
> So the weights are converted to integer values.

In the code, in `taggit_templatetags/templatetags/taggit_extras.py`, I see:

```
T_MAX = getattr(settings, 'TAGCLOUD_MAX', 6.0)
T_MIN = getattr(settings, 'TAGCLOUD_MIN', 1.0)
```

Is there any way I can access this through Django and change the settings? I'm having trouble plugging into the black box of Django and figuring out what is and is not possible. I thought of asking on the 'Issues' board, but the project looks kind of dead right now. I figured this was a general third-party installation question, so hoping to find someone here. Thank you for any help.

Comment: they mean you should add you own value of `TAGGIT_TAGCLOUD_MIN` to the settings.py of your django project https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

Comment: if you want to change only the _default_ values but not the specific values in your actual project, then yes you'd need to fork the app and change the lines you found in taggit_extras.py ...probably this is not what you want though!

Comment: Thank you! No, will fix that, meant specific values.

Comment: ok cool, this is a common pattern for 3rd party apps to integrate with django settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `settings.py` add two new properties

```
#This specifies the minimum of the weight attribute of a tagcloud's tags.
TAGGIT_TAGCLOUD_MIN = <yourvalue> 

#This specifies the maximum of the weight attribute of a tagcloud's tags.
TAGGIT_TAGCLOUD_MAX = <yourvalue>
```

The code you mentioned:

```
T_MAX = getattr(settings, 'TAGCLOUD_MAX', 6.0)
T_MIN = getattr(settings, 'TAGCLOUD_MIN', 1.0)
```

tries to get that values from settings, and if not found falls back to defaults (6.0 and 1.0)